# Python リストの要素と一致する辞書のキーとそのバリューを表示したい。

Tags: python

Python初心者のため、おかしな点があるかも知れません。指摘していただけると幸いです。

```
A(リスト) = ['さかな','とり','いぬ','ねこ','うさぎ']
B(辞書) = {'さかな':'まぐろ','かつお','いぬ':'しばいぬ','ぽめらにあん'}
```

(説明のために簡単なリストと辞書を書きましたが、本当はもっと多いです。)

上記のようなリストと辞書があったとして、Aの要素がBのキーに存在していた場合、キーとバリューを表示したいです。

結果が以下の様になると嬉しいです。

```
'さかな':'まぐろ','かつお'
'いぬ':'しばいぬ','ぽめらにあん'
```

Comment: こちらが応用できるのでは？ [Pythonで辞書のキーや値だけをリストとして取得する（keysとvalues）](https://www.mathpython.com/python-dictionary-key-list), [3. リストを集合型(set)に変換して論理積をとる。その結果をリストに変換する](https://qiita.com/yamao2253/items/309fdaa74b8f9d38ac46#3-%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%82%92%E9%9B%86%E5%90%88%E5%9E%8Bset%E3%81%AB%E5%A4%89%E6%8F%9B%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E8%AB%96%E7%90%86%E7%A9%8D%E3%82%92%E3%81%A8%E3%82%8B%E3%81%9D%E3%81%AE%E7%B5%90%E6%9E%9C%E3%82%92%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%81%AB%E5%A4%89%E6%8F%9B%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)

Answer (score 1):

`B` は以下の様な値(キーが文字列で値がリスト)だとします。

```py
A = ['さかな','とり','いぬ','ねこ','うさぎ']
B = {'さかな': ['まぐろ','かつお'], 'いぬ':['しばいぬ','ぽめらにあん']}

matched = {a: B[a] for a in A if a in B}
print(matched)

# {'さかな': ['まぐろ', 'かつお'], 'いぬ': ['しばいぬ', 'ぽめらにあん']}
```

Comment: 回答の前提が揃っていない質問に、勝手な予想で回答するのはやめましょう。
何らかの理由があってどうしてもそうしたい場合は、質問に対して追加した仮定を明確にしてから回答してください。

Answer (score 1):

解法例については既に回答されていますので，質問されている方が仰っている「おかしな点の指摘」を2点させていただきます。

(1) 辞書の記述

```
B = {'さかな': 'まぐろ', 'かつお', 'いぬ': 'しばいぬ', 'ぽめらにあん'}
```

「望む結果」からの推測ですが，辞書の別の表現形式（これは正しい記述）

```
B['さかな'] = 'まぐろ', 'かつお'
B['いぬ'] = 'しばいぬ', 'ぽめらにあん'
```

を波括弧の表現形式に当て嵌めたのだと思われますが，これはエラーになります。回避するには丸括弧を使う必要があります。

```
B = {'さかな': ('まぐろ', 'かつお'), 'いぬ': ('しばいぬ', 'ぽめらにあん')}
```

(2) 「A の要素が B のキーに存在していた場合，キーとバリューを表示」
おかしな点とまでは言えないのですが，表示する順序の指定があればより明確になります。選択肢としては「(a) A の順序 (b) B の順序（Python 3.7 以降可） (c) 不問」があり，それにより記述が変わってきます。普通に読めば (a) なので既に回答されている方は (a) を選択しているようです。一方，(c) で良いのであれば積集合（共通集合）が使えますので御参考として記述例を示します。

```
A = ['さかな', 'とり', 'いぬ', 'ねこ', 'うさぎ']
B = {'さかな': ('まぐろ', 'かつお'), 'いぬ': ('しばいぬ', 'ぽめらにあん')}

for k in set(A) & set(B.keys()):
    print(f"'{k}':", f"{B[k]}".strip('()'))
```

```
'いぬ': 'しばいぬ', 'ぽめらにあん'
'さかな': 'まぐろ', 'かつお'
```